# How do I send keepalive requests with websocket-client?

Tags: python, websocket

I need to add some code to send keepalive request every 5 seconds to the following program which is using [websocket-client](https://github.com/websocket-client/websocket-client)

```
def on_open(wsapp):
    wsapp.send(json.dumps(reqlogin))
    wsapp.send(json.dumps(reqsub))

def on_message(wsapp, msg):
    handle(msg)

wsapp = websocket.WebSocketApp(url, on_open=on_open, on_message=on_message)
wsapp.run_forever()
```

I've looked at [documentation](https://websocket-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) but couldn't find anything appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue using threading:

```
def on_open(wsapp):
    wsapp.send(json.dumps(reqlogin))
    wsapp.send(json.dumps(reqsub))

def on_message(wsapp, msg):
    handle(msg)

wsapp = websocket.WebSocketApp(url, on_open=on_open, on_message=on_message)
wsappthread = threading.Thread(target=wsapp.run_forever,
                               daemon=True)
wsappthread.start()
while True:
    time.sleep(5)
    wsapp.send(json.dumps(reqkeepalive))
```